# Adding a Sum to callendar

Tags: development

I want to Sum values String Values of percents{1/8, 2/8, 3/8, 4/8, 5/8, 6/8, 7/8, 8/8} which are strings. And I want to sum percent's in days. Only in this same day.
I write a code, but it isn't work:

```
        foreach (SPListItem olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt in listaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt)
        {

            e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#F5BCA9");
            e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
            e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(("<p style='color:blue; font-size:8px;'>" + olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Kontrakt"].ToString() + "</p><p style='color:#5D198E;'>" + olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Procenty"].ToString().Substring(3) + "</p>")));
            if(e.Day.Date.Date.ToUniversalTime() == e.Day.Date.Date.ToUniversalTime()){
                sumaProcentow += olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Procenty"].ToString().Substring(3);
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(("Suma = " + sumaProcentow)));
            }
```

Always add values from early dates. And it is "Suma = 4/84/84/84/85/83/83/83/83/83/8", And I only want to sum in one day.
[image]

Comment: I want only sum percent's in this the same day.

Comment: If we look for examle 30 day, so we have got 3/8 and 3/8, andthat is 6/8 Sum, so I want to write me "Suma = 6/8"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grzegorz,

You can use SPQuery to get all the items for that day... and then loop through the items and sum them up!

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>" + e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString() + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
SPListItemCollection itemColl = calendarList.GetItems(query);
int NumeratorSum = 0, DenominatorSum = 0;
foreach(SPListItem item in itemColl)
{
    NumeratorSum += int.Parse(item["Procenty"].ToString().Split('/')[0]);
    DenominatorSum += int.Parse(item["Procenty"].ToString().Split('/')[1]);
}

e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(("Suma = " + NumeratorSum.ToString() + "/" + DenominatorSum.ToString())));
```

Comment: It can't uderstand this line.
` "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>" + e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString() + "</Value></Eq></Where>";`
A lot of errors come

Comment: There schould be query.Query?

Comment: yes query.Query - just a typo mistake :).. I am glad it worked!

Comment: I'm glad too :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Whole Code luks like:

```
      foreach (SPListItem olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt in listaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt)
            {

                e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#F5BCA9");
                e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(("<p style='color:blue; font-size:8px;'>" + olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Kontrakt"].ToString() + "</p><p style='color:#5D198E;'>" + olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Procenty"].ToString().Substring(3) + "</p>")));

                var query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Dzien' /><Value Type='DateTime'>" + e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString() + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
                SPListItemCollection itemColl = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"].GetItems(query);
                int sumaProcentow = 0;
                foreach (SPListItem item in itemColl)
                {
                    sumaProcentow += int.Parse(olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Procenty"].ToString().Split('/')[1]);
                }

                e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(("Suma = " + sumaProcentow.ToString())));

            }
```

Thanks **Arsalan Adam Khatri**

Comment: Only I have got problem with Split('/'), because I want to show all number, not only 8. All number this is "4/8"

Answer (score 0):

I done this like this, whole Code:

```
 // Gdy nie ma zaznaczonej osoby to wtedy wyświetlamy wszystkie daty urlopów 
            foreach (SPListItem olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt in listaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt)
            {

                e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#F5BCA9");
                e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(("<p style='color:blue; font-size:8px;'>" + olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Kontrakt"].ToString() + "</p><p style='color:#5D198E;'>" + olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Procenty"].ToString().Substring(3) + "</p>")));

                var query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Dzien' /><Value Type='DateTime'>" + e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString() + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
                SPListItemCollection itemColl = witryna.Lists["Szczegoly"].GetItems(query);
                int sumaProcentow = 0;
                foreach (SPListItem item in itemColl)
                {
                    int index;

                    index = olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Procenty"].ToString().IndexOf("#");
                    string procentKolejny = Convert.ToString(olistaDniPrzeznaczonychNaProjekt["Procenty"]).Substring(index + 1,1);

                    sumaProcentow += int.Parse(procentKolejny);
                }

                e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(("Suma = " + sumaProcentow.ToString()+"/8")));

            }
        }
```

But now I see two times or more sum in the calendar. I must see only one time.
[image]